# From darkness to light?

Tags: meaning

> **From darkness to light**
>     The fruits of his labours became the  ‘Gaia’ theory,  which was outlined in a book published in 1979,  in which Lovelock makes the analogy between the earth and living organisms.  Like our body,  which remains  at a constant  temperature because our organs collaborate with one another,  a system is maintained in homeostasis thanks to the activity of its component parts. Lovelock goes as far as to say that our planet is alive,  self-regulated by complex positive and negative feedback mechanisms,  involving the living as much as the non-living.  ‘In the 19th century our world was perceived as a relatively frozen system in which the living fought to adapt.  It is only in the 20th century that scientists have  gradually become aware of the role of organisms and of their interaction in the configuration of the atmosphere,  the oceans and the rocks above  ground.  Our environment is not an inert structure,  but rather a vestigial remnant of our ancestors’  evolution.'
>     Gaia immediately aroused enthusiasm from the emerging ecological movement,  which perceived Lovelock as a valuable scientific supporter.  Their enthusiasm quickly curbed: the man was a fervent defender of nuclear power, which did not sit well with the green movement at the time.  From the perspective of the scientific community,  the theory was regarded with scepticism and the reference to Gaia,  the earth goddess in Greek mythology,  added to Lovelock’s disrepute.  ‘Gaia interested climatologists,  but profoundly displeased the rest of the scientific community,  particularly the biologists who,  most notably,  accused me of casting doubt on Darwin’s theories.’ 
>     For biologists,  it is impossible that any type of collaboration could be established between organisms in permanent competition with one another.  Lovelock replied by developing Daisyworld,  a computer model conceived to illustrate the earth’s feedback mechanisms. It  uses a basic biotope,  black and white daisies, to regulate temperature alone.  During the first simulation phase,  the temperature is low and the black flowers grow rapidly,  because they channel the sunlight better.  This warms up the planet,  which allows the white flowers to grow. At the end of the day,  the two types of daisies survive and the fact that they are in competition with one another actually helps maintain the optimal temperature of the entire biotope. It was a perfect example of the positive and negative feedback mechanisms that form  the basis of the Gaia theory.

What does "From darkness to light" mean here?
    Doesn't it refer to the acceptance of 'Gaia' theory by scientists?

Comment: Do you mean the repetition of the title at the beginning, apparently caused by a formatting error?

Comment: "From darkness to light" is a pretty common metaphor to illustrate a journey towards greater understanding, or "enlightenment". Have you done any research at all?

Comment: Lovelock proved the positive and negative feedback mechanisms that form the basis of the Gaia theory by developing Daizyworld. Do you think they meant this as an enlightenment and gave this title?

Comment: The article given is an opinion article.  "From darkness to light" is (as noted by @Astralbee) is a common metaphor to indicate greater understanding.  In the author's opinion, Lovelock provided greater understanding to biology.

Comment: Have you checked a dictionary for "darkness" and "light" to see what other meanings they have?

Answer (score 1):

There are many metaphors about darkness and light.

If you are **in the dark**, you don't know, you are not informed.

If something **comes to light**, it becomes known publicly.

**Darkness** usually suggests *ignorance, unknowing, oblivion*, whereas **light** means *knowledge, understanding, enlightenment*.

Then, the title **from darkness to light** could mean a path towards the acceptance/acknowledgment of his theory (and the evolution of it), or, as @Astralbee pointed out, its important contribution to our understanding of life. Or both.